# How to move bone according to tracked body movement using kinect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender, virtual-reality, kinect-v2

I am new to Unity and Kinect v2. I am creating a virtual dressing room application on my own. I need some help in cloth movement along with body. I have mapped bone of gameObject with Skeleton Joint. Shin Bone is working fine. But I am unble to map Hip bone. Can anyone help me with this ? I have  mapped Thigh bone of gameObject with hip bone of skeleton and Shin bone of gameobject with Knee of skeleton. Knee is moving fine but Hip not.[image]

Comment: Yeah, good luck. This was something I told my previous boss, "Look, it's not that simple..."

Comment: Can you please help me with this?

Comment: No, because it was not something I *accomplished.* The data in is so different than the data needed that it's not an easy task. What you **have now** is more than I managed.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion on this? I mean how I can achieve this ?

Comment: I do not. Sorry. :\

Answer (score -1):

Mocap data is a location of points, you have one point as the location of the hip, another for the location of the knee...

An armature is a collection of bones that each define two points that are connected. Most bones are parented to another bone, so if you rotate the upper leg, the knee, foot and toes all follow along.

In your example image you only have a knee that has moved, instead of moving the knee joint, you should rotate the upper leg bone so that the lower end points to the new position of the knee. As a child of the upper leg, the lower leg and foot will follow along to the appropriate position.

Start from the hip, point the upper leg to the knee, then point the lower leg to the ankle, then the foot to the toes.

Comment: Thanks sambler for suggestion, can you please I have rotate bones but it is not moving properly with legs can you please provide me example or sample of code it would be appropriated